# what does the int position parameter do in the getView method in android?

Tags: android

i have used a hashmap to store data in a custom adapter i have made by extending the `BaseAdapter` class in android. 
in the 'getCount' method i am returning the no.of keys in the hashmap that i have populated before.
now when i come to the `getView` method , it has a parameter called int position. 
i don't understand the funcitonality of this parameter...

everytime `getView` is called isn't this integer incremented by one?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `ListView` class calls the `getView()` method every time one of its items becomes visible. So the `position` arguments is this item's position.

Comment: so everytime getView is called , this should get updated , right?

Comment: Every time the `getView()` method is called, the `ListView` asks you to create or reuse a view to display an item at a given position from an adapter. I don't understand what you mean this in your question. The 'ListView` is going to be updated and the `position` argument is likely to be changed.

Comment: i have an array from which i need to get data. so every time a getView is called i need to get fresh data from my array to be displayed in the listview,for this i need the index of my array to be updated. assuming arg0 is incrementing everytime getview is called i can use arg0 as my index. this will save me the trouble of not keeping a separate variable to do the same.

Comment: If you're using `Adapter` in a correct way, you don't have any other possibility to get an index of an item that you need to display.

Comment: so arg0 that comes as a parameter does increment everytime getview is called? yes / no?

Comment: No. Let's assume that items 10-20 are displaying at the moment. You're scrolling the `ListView` and item 9 is becoming visible. That means item 20 is becoming invisible. The `getView()` method will be called with the `position` argument equal to 9. And possibly, the `convertView` view argument will contain a view that was used to display item 20. That's because the `ListView` caches child views to decrease memory footprint and improve performance.

Comment: but if there are 4 views that can be visible at a time, then at first before i have ever scrolled or done anything, four views would be populated, this means that arg0 should move from 0 to 3. right?

Comment: It depends on the `ListView` implementation, but I think yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

The `arg0` doesn't keep on incrementing. It is nothing but the index of the item in your list.

Please set the `layout_height` of the ListView to `fill_parent` so that `getView()` gets called only once before you start scrolling.

The `arg0` starts from 0 and goes till the size of your list. When you start scrolling, it  again starts from 0 and goes on.

Hope this solves your question.